# What datatype is used to store binary number (base2 numbers) in SQL Server other than using varchar datatype

Tags: sql-server, binary

I am intending to use bit wise operation like http://www.codespread.com/sql-bitwise-operator-can-simplify-db-design.html
since records in the table will increase to billions in future.

To retain the performance, I thought to use binary number mapping and use binary datatype in a SQL Server table to store binary numbers like 2 will be stored as 00000010.

How should I store 00000010 in binary column? Or what datatype should I use to store binary numbers? Since operations on binary numbers (base2) is faster in SQL Server, I don't want to store 00000010 as `varchar` datatype and use only binary datatype.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".  That is a bit of an overstatement, but you should design the system so it works first and then worry about micro-optimizations.

Comment: [This page](http://improve.dk/converting-between-base-2-10-and-16-in-t-sql/) might be useful to you.

Comment: what datatype should I use to store binary numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would want to using the **VARBINARY** data type;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188362.aspx

SELECT CAST( 2 AS VARBINARY );

Comment: When you say no success what do you mean? The data won't be inserted into column? or you cant perform operations? Please edit your answer to show the code that isn't working